# How to make composite key restrict only dates without matching time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005.

I have a composite key comprising of these columns:

UserID ..... int

ADate  ..... datetime

If I enter two similar dates with different time for a user, it is permitting that record. But I want it to restrict because of similar dates.

How to make it restrict when identical date parts are inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your table

```
create table tbl (
    userid int,
    adate datetime
)
```

You can add a COMPUTED column

```
alter table tbl add adateonly as datediff(d,0,adate);
```

So that you can create a UNIQUE constraint over it:

```
alter table tbl add constraint uq_tbl_date unique(userid, adateonly);
```

Comment: OK, I will try and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question you want to create a composite restriction with and index or other method?

1) With an index, can you add another column varchar(8) with just the date like: yyyymmdd, then with a trigger or before the inserts you can generate the date string.

2) create a trigger on the table and validate the the two keys, probably a insert and update trigger.

hope this helps,
José Cruz